# Transforming xml to edi in mule

Tags: xml, mule, edi

How can I convert an xml file to edi in mule sb.
I am looking for some suggestions which provides step by step guide.
The documentation at mulesoft site is not very clear and no clear examples.

The Output EDI File :

```
UNH+1+RESPONSE:D:99A:UN:ANZ21'
BGM+7+7869626+9+AP'
DTM+137:20150928091050:204'
DOC+640+31267937'
DTM+137:20150928090000:204'
NAD+MS'
ERC+COM0000'
FTX+AAO+++Message received without error'
RFF+EQD:MOAU6747861'
UNT+10+0'
```

Comment: You want to do it with enterprise or community edition ?

Comment: can you post your xml and edi structure ?

Comment: @Mauro Rocco: I want to do it with enterprise edition

Comment: @Naveen Raj : In my original question, I have added the input xml and output edi files

Comment: Hi, what is not clear in this page https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-b2b/edifact-module it just explains what you want to do it, not enough ?

Comment: @Mauro Roco: What I am not clear is the transformation part of input to output. For example, how I can map one particular field in the xml suppose "argo:msgReferenceNbr" to the edi file

Comment: If you DO READ the docs it says that the connector accepts and produces a precise java objec structure made of LinkedHashMap and ArrayList, therefore you need to transform your XML in a Java Map with the proper structure for example using datamapper or even manually using xpath. https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-b2b/edifact-module#understanding-the-mule-message-structure-for-edifact-documents. If you want my 2 cents, configure the module for read a sample edifact look at the java object it generates and than just produce the same object for writing.

Comment: @Mauro Rocco : Thanks for that suggestion. I will try accordingly. Lets see if that helps.

Comment: @Mauro Rocco: Hi, Can you point tutorial on writing esl files. I have one esl file in my project. That was developed as part of poc.  I see some imports like : imports: [ '/edifact/d98b/basedefs.esl' ]. Is this esl file something generic as I do not see any basedefs.esl in my project. Also can you guide to write esl for above edi file pasted?